# Android ListView Selector Color

Tags: android, android-listview

**Hi All,**

I have 2 questions regarding a ListView in Android:

1. How can I **get** the color of the listview's focused row ?
   I tried to use the **ListView.getSelector()** method, which according to its documentation should give me what I'm looking for, but it's giving me a Drawable object which I don't know how to retrieve the color from (if possible...).
2. How can I **set** the color of the listview's focused row ?
   Here I tried to use the **setSelector()** method on the listview, passing it a ColorDrawable object, but the result of doing it is that the whole background of the list view is painted in that color... and this is not what I wanted of course...

Thanks!

Comment: This may help (there is both question and solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065430/fixed-android-detecting-focus-pressed-color

Comment: It seems there is a bug in Android 2 that causes the colour to affect the whole background - check my answer that links to a workaround provided on another question.

Answer (score 89):

The list selector drawable is a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) — it contains reference to multiple drawables for each state the list can be, like selected, focused, pressed, disabled...

While you can retrieve the drawable using `getSelector()`, I don't believe you can retrieve a specific `Drawable` from a `StateListDrawable`, nor does it seem possible to programmatically retrieve the colour directly from a `ColorDrawable` anyway.

As for setting the colour, you need a `StateListDrawable` as described above.  You can set this on your list using the `android:listSelector` attribute, defining the drawable in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I'd also move assigning the list selector to a custom theme, so all lists in your application would look same
<item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/my_list_highlight</item>

Comment: This does not work with API 7/8 at least. It seems to change the whole background to the same pressed color when pressed, including background of other rows, and also the margin lines (I have black) between rows.

Comment: @Jonny it works for me when using drawables, but not when using colours. Have added answer referencing a good workaround that works for colours.

Comment: Hello I am trying to use a selector in my listview like you have suggested but it has got 9 pngs and not colours , Also I have a custom layout that I inflate in my listview and use selector as background of that custom layout , Can you suggest?

Answer (score 11):

TO ADD: [@Christopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2038086/383414) does not work on API 7/8 (as per @Jonny's correct comment) IF you are using colours, instead of drawables. (In my testing, using drawables as per Christopher works fine)

Here is the **FIX for 2.3 and below** when using colours:

- [Android: Entire ListView changes color on focus, not just ListView child item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10490435/383414)

As per @Charles Harley, there is a bug in 2.3 and below where filling the list item with a colour causes the colour to flow out over the whole list. His fix is to define a `shape` drawable containing the colour you want, and to use that instead of the colour.

I suggest looking at this link if you want to just use a colour as selector, and are targeting Android 2 (or at least allow for Android 2).

Comment: This bit me again just now, thank you for reminding me what the real issue is.