# change background color on list item selection android

Tags: android

hello frnds i want to change background color (white on selection) of list on selection of list in listview and if i select any other position then first selected row comes to its previous state and currently selected rows background become white.so how to do this

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
    super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);

    //do some stuff here      

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected"+(position+1)+"th item",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do that in code, since you later on might want to change colors, and you shouldn't have "layout/styling" code hardcoded.

Do instead create a style, and apply that to the ListView in your xml. You can read about how you do that in this thread:
[ListSelector applies to the entire list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183447/listselector-applies-to-the-entire-list)

Comment: should have been a comment since this is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your list view click listener:

```
yourlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {                            
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                      int position, long arg3) {
        yourAdapter.toggleSelected(position);
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();              
    }       
});
```

Then make an `ArrayList` in your adapter and initialize it to store all the positions of your list view items:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int length = yourmainarraylist.size();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    selectedIds.add(0);             
}
```

then put a check in `getView` to toggle the background:

```
if (selectedIds.get(position)==1)
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_row_selected);
else
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_row);
```

and put this method in your adapter

```
public void toggleSelected(int position) {
    selectedIds.set(position, (selectedIds.get(position) == 0));
}
```