# Android tablet not showing any ListView data

Tags: android, android-layout

i have develop android application using webservice,all the data comes from webservice,
that application works very well on android mobile phone but when i tried with gottab tablet
its not showing any data on listview..
Please anyone help me to resolve the issues

Comment: show us the code which you are using for list view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530940/why-is-my-listview-not-showing-anything

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089269/android-list-view-selected-item-style-not-showing-until-user-scrolls