# Android Listview Selected Item color must remain changed even if finger is lifted up

Tags: android, listview, layout

I followed many questions like this 1 [change color of selected listview item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442999/change-color-of-selected-listview-item), but found nothing useful.

I have a list view and what I want is, the selected item must be highlighted e.g blue color, even after user has lifted his finger.

this is my row_color.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/light_sea_green" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/light_sea_green" />

</selector>
```

and this is my layout which is inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/row_color">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_game_row_face"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/af025501" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this one to ur selector

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

This will be ur default drawable.

You can remove

```
 <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

UPDATE ->

Here's a code snippet that could help you -

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

/* Your code reusing code here */

    if(position == selectedItemPosition which you must save in onItemClickListener of the listview)
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(selecteditem background color);
    }
    else {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(normal background color);
    }

}
```

The else part is very important. Otherwise it will cause recycled views to carry the same bg color.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it is not even showing selector color, and my problem is still unsolved

Comment: You are setting color as row_color while your selector file name is row.xml. So is this a copy paste error?

Comment: o sorry, yes it is copy paste error, I have edited my question

Comment: Create this transparent color(#00000000) in your color.xml and use it here. See if that helps.

Comment: main problem is, the tag <item android:state_selected>.... </...>, in not working, rest of the code is working even state_pressed is working

Comment: Sorry. I misread your question. you have to store the position of the item selected and in your getView if position is the one that is selected you have to set the color yourself.

Comment: I did but when I scroll listview, other (random) positions also get highlighted, if you have code or link to any example please share with me

Comment: @sHaXahid, make sure you are setting the positions that aren't selected to the default color. When views get recycled you retain the background that was set on them previously.

Comment: @sHaXahid Please check my update. That must fix your problem.

Comment: can you post your getView() function in your adapter?