# Custom item selector drawn over complete GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

in my project I have several GridViews. The default item selector is device dependent, on my Acer tablet its yellow, on my Motorola phone its blue.

I want it to be gray for all devices.

So I googled and SOed around and found that I have to put a `android:listSelector` attribute to my GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/labeled_gridview_gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:columnWidth="125dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" >
</GridView>
```

Where `list_selector.xml` is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/selector_item">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/black">
    </item>

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white">
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white">
    </item>
</selector>
```

My problem is now: When I click on a GridView item the **whole GridView background becomes black**. Which is not what I want. I tried putting the `android:listSelector` attribute to the GridView item layout, but it didn't do anything.

Is my selector wrong? Or my GridView? Help me plz!

Comment: Probably too late, but in case anyone else is having this problem, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5155600/663370

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Holo theme? They make sure that the design looks the same on all kind of devices.

Comment: I use a custom theme all over my app. Also my app targets 2.X, 3.X and 4.x Android version. The default theme changed from version to version, didnt it? Also many manufacturer use their own themes to override the default.

Comment: They are not allowed to overwrite the holo theme. So make sure that your theme is derived from Holo.

Comment: Android is open source dude, manufacturers can do what ever they want. Google just does some "testing" so the device can get on the play store.

Comment: Dude, all devices shipping with Google Play Store are bound to few rules. See also 'If the device has Android Market it will have the Holo themes as they were originally designed.' (link: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html)