# How to set color of selected item in ListFragment in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I have a `listview` in `ListFragment` which gets populated from an adapter, I want to highlight the clicked (or selected) item in the list as well as do some action based on the selection. I am able to handle the event but How do I set the color of selected item from the list.

Comment: use the `android:listselector`

Comment: Check this out.
This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183447/listselector-applies-to-the-entire-list

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a `ListFragment` then you might not be specifying a `ListView` in XML which means you'll need to set the `listSelector` in code. Be careful not to set it too early in the activity life-cycle though as you'll end up with an `IllegalStateException`.

level_list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level_gradient_bg" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/level_gradient_bg_hover" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/level_gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

Fragment:

```
public class LevelFragment extends ListFragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //Create view 
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.level_list_selector);
    }
}
```

Note: if you're using a custom layout for the cell rows, you'll need to set the list selector on that too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/level_list_selector"
    android:padding="5dip" >
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a selector file with your needed states. That will provide solution for you. For example -

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_highlighted" /> <!--  @drawable/tab_focus -->

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_pressed" /> <!--  @drawable/tab_press -->

</selector>
```

In your `ListView` set this selector as listselector. Ex,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector" />
```

Have a look at these examples -

1. [ListSelector applies to the entire list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2183447/940096)
2. [ListView with selector](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/)
3. [Listview_and_list_selector](http://www.anddev.org/listview_and_list_selectorurgent-t1594.html)

Comment: Thanks but where do I set to color?

Comment: @AyushGoyal instead of `@drawable/bg_list_item_highlighted` and `@drawable/bg_list_item_pressed` You can set the colours there.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I edited my question: its a ListFragment so I dont have any xml file for it. Everthing is supposed to be handled in java itself.

Answer (score 1):

for this you have to make a drawable as the background of your list items. and after  "selected" any item from the lisView, set the drawable to be transparent or #000.so when item will select selector you maid will show.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://meta.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/BackgroundColor" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want standard ListView behaviour in your ListFragment, you can set your list item row layout to use ?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator as background. Like so:

**ListItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" <!--This is the important bit-->
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ListFragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="No data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your ListFragment fragment code, use the custom layout (this is mono code, but do not despair):

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListFragment, container, false);
                //... do stuff
    }
```

Some place in the code where you want to create adapter, use the ListItem layout. In this case a SimpleAdapter mapping data to a Icon and Text view. the backgound in the ListItem.xml (?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator) makes the item behave as you see in a normal list:

```
var list = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>(listOfStuff.Count);
foreach (AMap map in listOfStuff) {
        var dictionary = new JavaDictionary<string, object> {
            {"text", map.Text}, {"icon", Resource.Drawable.SomeIcon}
        };
        list.Add(dictionary);
}
SimpleAdapter _adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Activity, list,
                                         Resource.Layout.ListItem,
                                         new string[] { "text", "icon" },
                                         new int[] { Resource.Id.text,
                                         Resource.Id.icon });
```

Answer (score 0):

in adapter class in get view method() u can do that as ..

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setTag(position);

            if(ur condition){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            }else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: I used this but it is setting the color permanently, I want to remove the color when some other item is selected.