# Is there a way to have similar behavior with listSelector in Android 2.2. and 4.1

Tags: android, selector, listitem

I'm using listSelector in order to change listItem color when pressed.

In Emulator and on Android 4.1 device it all looks good, but on Android 2.2 device, instead that list item changes color, the whole list gets purple (all items), not just the selected item.

I use:
android:listSelector="@drawable/purpulefocus" which when pressed changes background to purple.

I wonder if there is a behavior change between Android versions, or some issue with my device, because I can't figure out what could cause this behavior change.

Tnx.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvRecepies1list"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/purpulefocus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you show your Listview xml file ?

Comment: There is not much to see, and I've placed single line that is important.... this works on Android 4.1, and not working on 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution using "Shapes" like in example:

```
<item android:state_focused="true">
<shape>
    <solid android:color="#66000000" />
</shape>
</item>
```

From Example here: [ListSelector applies to the entire list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183447/listselector-applies-to-the-entire-list)

Answer (score 0):

2.3 and below expect the selector to be set as a background of the list item. So basically you must add the selector to the list and, to get it work on 2.3 and below, you need to add the same drawable reference as a background to the root element of your item you use as a ListView row.