# Proper way to do a list selector for a tablet (two-pane) view?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml

Currently, my list selector is:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/half" android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/full" android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/half" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

It works, but there are some oddities. For example, "hovering" over items (as in, going over them with the d-pad/trackball) shows the full glow, rather than the half glow.

I just don't really get these list selectors.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. You can use `hierarchyviewer` to inspect the state of your view when it is focused with the track ball. That might yield a clue or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem in your selector file. You are combining two states `Focus` and `Selected`. May be this combination is not happening when you use the d-pad for focus the item.
You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728343/630668 to solve your issue.