# GridView listSelector on Gingerbread highlights entire grid

Tags: android, gridview, android-2.3-gingerbread

Working with a `GridView` and trying to have the selected item highlight in grey. This works fine until I tested it on Android 2.3. On Android 2.3, this is what happens when you select an item:

[image: GridView with selection]

In this screenshot I had tapped on the Restaurants item. Essentially the entire `GridView` gets highlighted in grey and not the selected item. However, in Android 4.0+ this `GridView` works as expected and tapping on items correctly highlights them (not the `GridView`!) in grey.

Here is the relavent part of my layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/categories_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_view_selector"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And here is `res/drawable/list_view_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5155600/119362) workaround, but it just results in nothing getting highlighted at all (not even the selected item) on both 2.3 and 4.0+ devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the selector to the `background` of the item layout instead and set `android:listSelector="@null"`.

**Grid:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/categories_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Item:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_view_selector">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixes the issue on both 4.0+ and 2.3 devices.

Comment: In my case, it was showing space around a gridview without selecting it. android:listSelector="@null" cleared the problem, but i dont understand why?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/calendergrid"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         android:background="@drawable/listselectorforgridview"
        >
</TextView>
```

Just paste that and use like...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dateadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                R.layout.textviewforcalendergrid, calenderdays);
```