# Android - Drawer menu list item doesn't change colour on click when inflated by custom adapter

Tags: android

My drawer layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
     <ListView
       android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
       android:dividerHeight="0.1dp" 
       android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
      />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My list row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_item_image"
        android:contentDescription="Menu item image" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Then the getView method in my custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View drawerRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_row, parent, false);
    TextView drawerRowText = (TextView) drawerRow
            .findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_item);
    ImageView drawerRowImage = (ImageView) drawerRow
            .findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_item_image);

    drawerRowText.setText(drawerRowTextValues[position]);
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        drawerRowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.content_new_dark);
        break;
    case 1:
        drawerRowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.location_web_site_dark);
        break;
    case 2:
        drawerRowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_settings_dark);
        break;
    }

    drawerRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("drawer list item clicked...");

        }
    });

    return drawerRow;
}
```

I can verify that the event is fired just can't see the list item colour changing(flashing) on click as opposed to when using ArrayAdapter for example.

Any ideas folks?

**EDIT:**
OK, I got almost the desired behaviour by adding a listSelector as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed state. -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_row_pressed_bg"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

... adding that listSelector to my listView above with the following line:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
```

My only problem now is that the pressed-state color doesn't fill in the whole item row in the list:
[image]

Comment: But I don't see you changing the color. Your onClick doesn't do anything other than printing a message…??

Comment: Neither do I when using the ArrayAdapter but it works. When using the ArrayAdapter I have exactly the same TextView but on click flashes the list item.

Comment: "flashes" or just briefly marks it as selected? Are you maybe seeing the default ListView Selector? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector)

Comment: "briefly marks it as selected", pardon me. So how can I make use of the listSelector? I tried adding it to the list above without any luck.

Comment: You can set any drawable (with states!) as a listselector. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector). So when you touch it, the drawable is displayed (usually a bkg color for example). See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183447/listselector-applies-to-the-entire-list

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with the listSelector but now the color doesn't fill in the whole whole row item at its width. Please see my screenshot above.

Comment: I was oing to tell you, to fill the row… but someone already did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your LinearLayout's width to fill the row like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    ...
```