# How to highlight pressed items in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using this code below, but it doesn't work properly: If I select an item, the background is changed. But the background change also if I put only focus on the item without selecting it. Why ?

Added to my listview:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_key"
```

**@drawable/bg_key**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    android:id="@+id/myselector"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_activated="false"
        android:drawable="@color/activated_color" />

</selector>
```

**color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="activated_color">#1d1d1d</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Maybe use the `pressed` and the `focused` states?

Comment: @Rotwang I have added state_pressed="true" state_focused="false" and view.setPressed(true); in the onItemClick method, but it still doesn't work

Comment: `Added to my listview...` isn't it a *per item* choice?

Comment: @Rotwang it's a listselector

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7586486/2649012

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight/provide ripple effect to your list items using the following :

Create a selector item_ripple.xml in your drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/activated_color"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Create a selector item_ripple.xml in your drawable-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/activated_color">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

You need to add these selector as background of your item layout :

```
android:background="@drawable/item_ripple"
```

Comment: what is drawable-v21 ?

Comment: Create a new directory in your res folder and name it as drawable-v21. This signifies if the current API version of OS is <=21, consider using the resources present in this folder, if not present, resources under drawable folder are used by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pressed** state in your selector file

**/drawable/list_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

then set following attribute in your listView

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```