# Change icons of checked and unchecked for Checkbox for Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, icons

Instead of having a check mark for the icon, I want a custom star (I have checked and unchecked icons). Can this be done through a property? Or must I declare a custom widget that derives from Checkbox?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Kind of a mix:

Set it in your layout file :-

```
 <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="new checkbox"
           android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" 
           android:button="@drawable/checkbox" />
```

where the @drawable/checkbox will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background_focus_yellow" />
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background_focus_yellow" />
 <item android:state_checked="false"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background" />
 <item android:state_checked="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Same as with any other checkbox (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html). You can make use of of this method if manually want to set it to check or unchecked: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked(boolean)

Comment: @ggomeze what if we want to change the size of text as well ??

Comment: Have you tried scale within the Checkbox?: android:scaleX="1.5" and android:scaleY="1.5"

Comment: `android:button` property doesn't work on pre-Lollipop devices

Comment: @soshial  what should be the preferred compat method then?

Answer (score 14):

it's `android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"`
to make it work

Answer (score 14):

This may be achieved by using `AppCompatCheckBox`. You can use `app:buttonCompat="@drawable/selector_drawable"` to change the selector.

It's working with PNGs, but I didn't find a way for it to work with Vector Drawables.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been struggling for days. Only your solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative would be to use a drawable/textview instead of a checkbox and manipulate it accordingly. I have used this method to have my own checked and unchecked images for a task application.