# How to change check box tick color in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I am developing android application In that i use check box but default check box tick color is blue so i want to change that color to yellow. is there any inbuilt property to set color to check box tick.

Comment: Here is the solution: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192173/change-icons-of-checked-and-unchecked-for-checkbox-for-android)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Unfortunately, changing the color of checkbox check mark isn't a simple attribute

Create a selector xml file in `res\drawables\` folder with name `cb_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

In your layout file apply this file to your checkBox

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:text="My CheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/cb_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Add a `unchecked.png`, and `checked.png` in your `drawables` folder. These are checked and unchecked image of checkbox.

Comment: this made my checkbox disappear O_O

Comment: you will have to have border around images to show box, one image will be empty border and other with the tick image

Comment: Disappear because u used color changes in android:drawable="@drawable/checked". U need image!

Answer (score 29):

You can use the attribute `app:buttonTint` of the `AppCompatCheckBox` from the android.support.v7 library.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Advantage: works also below API 21 and you don't need to redraw the checkbox.

Answer (score 11):

As of API 21 you can use the Button Tint attribute

```
android:buttonTint="#FFFF00"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this programmatically, then you simply do this:

```
final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
cb.setButtonTintList(getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Chris Stillwell's answer gave me the idea to try this as I couldn't simply set the colour using the attributes.  :)

Comment: Also in xml:  `android:buttonTint="@color/arancioneMedium"`

Comment: I had to use: `cb.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources()
.getColor(R.color.colorAccent, null)));`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change only tint color than must go with the below solution. Its work perfectly.
Create a Selector "check_box_tint.xml" in your res/drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/your_checked_color" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/your_unchecked_color" />
</selector>
```

Now Use this drawable as color of your checkbox tint.

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/cbSelectAll"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:buttonTint="@drawable/check_box_tint"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to styles.xml and add this line.

```
<style>
<item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item> 
</style>
```

using this you can change color or set different color

Comment: seriosly your comment works fine but what have you written in your answer

Comment: Wouldn't changing your theme change way more than just the checkboxes?

Comment: @Nicolas Carrasco Well, as long as you create a id for this style and apply it only to the check-boxes it wouldn't...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we must create a drawable that include checked and uncheck color situations, then you must set this drawable as buttonTint;

drawable_checkbox;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/kelleyGreen" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/warmGrey" />
</selector>
```

```
<style name="CheckBox" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Regular.XSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/warmGrey</item>
    <item name="buttonTint">@drawable/drawable_checkbox</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version:

```
checkBox.buttonTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.colorPrimary)
```

Comment: Note: valueOf() takes a color value, not a color resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom selector for the checkbox.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/patch_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/patch_normal" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/patchdisable" android:state_enabled="false"/>


</selector>
```

Like this.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for an answer (I am aware this is an older question) – I found this solution works well without having to worry about API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31840734/7601437

In short: create a style for the checkbox, e.g. `checkboxStyle` and then implement it as a theme: `android:theme="@style/checkboxStyle"`

Answer (score 0):

For applying color programmatically it will require API Level >19 if your min sdk is >19 then you can use

```
checkbox[i]!!.setButtonTintList(getColorStateList(activity!!,R.color.green))

 OR
```

view.setButtonTintList(getColorStateList(activity!!,R.color.green))

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works than use AppCompatCheckBox with app:buttonCompat="your_drawable_selector"

This is working with png.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked very well for checkbox selected and unselected color change

```
val states = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked),
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked)
)
val colors = intArrayOf(
    requireContext().getColor(R.color.unchecked_color),
    requireContext().getColor(R.color.checked_color)
)
val colorStateList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
checkbox.buttonTintList = colorStateList
```