# How to change the tick color in Appcompact Checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, themes

I am working in checkbox android.The requirement  is When i checked the checkbox the tick color should change to white and checkbox background should change to the mentioned color but here i am not getting tick color in white.I attached my code below please take a took and suggest me proper solution.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/optIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Email_optin"
            app:buttonTint="@color/primary_color"

           /> 


   <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#9C27B0</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFC107</item>
```

Comment: check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542693/how-to-change-check-box-tick-color-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the tick color, you need to change the color of coloraccent in res/values/colors.xml as

```
  <color name="colorAccent">#0071a6</color>
```