# How to change CheckBox color in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm new to Android development and I'm following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_checkbox_control.htm) tutorial for showing a `Checkbox` in Android. `Checkbox` showing properly.

But I want to change the checkbox color. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without changing the drawable using buttonTint (as of API 23):

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/CHECKMARK_COLOR_HERE" />
```

or use AppCombatCheckBox for older versions of android/compatibility.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:buttonTint="@color/CHECKMARK_COLOR_HERE" />
```

More answer is there in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542693/how-to-change-check-box-tick-color-in-android) link