# Android : Change checkbox color (boxbackground and tick mark color)

Tags: android, user-interface, checkbox, styles

I am using checkbox as below

[image: checkbox img]

My code...

```
   <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="10"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

style.xml

```
 <style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#ff0000</item>       
 </style>
```

I can change the box color by changing the color in style xml.As i am using

```
 android:button="@null"
 android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

I couldnt find a way to change the tick color.
I need to change the tick color (which is blue) coming as the background color.
How can i do that.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change check box tick color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542693/how-to-change-check-box-tick-color-in-android)

Comment: No.. i am using a diffrent code to align my checkbox and text vertically. so cant use that method

Answer (score 3):

Create a selector XML file in `res\drawables\` folder with name `cb_selector`.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

In your layout file apply this file to your checkBox

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:text="My CheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/cb_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Add a `unchecked.png`, and `checked.png` in your drawable folder. These are checked and unchecked image of a checkbox.

You can use `color` instead of `drawable` also

Comment: Doing that makes us lose the nice animation effect

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using AppCompatCheckBox with app:buttonCompat="@drawable/your_selector_drawable".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically in following way ( if you want to preserve material theme animations):

```
ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}}, new int[]{getColor(R.color.checked), getColor(R.color.unchecked_color)});
        binding.checkbox.setButtonTintList(myColorStateList);
```

If you want to use custom drawables for checkbox, you can do it like @Nensi did it in the answer above.