# How to change AppCompatCheckBox tick color?

Tags: android, checkbox

Here is my `AppCompatCheckBox`

```
     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="hello123"
                        android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

`MyCheckBox` style

```
    <style name="MyCheckBox" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorAccent">#ffff00</item> <--yellow
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff00ff</item> <--purple
    </style>
```

checked = true
[image]

checked = false
[image]

How to change the **tick** color

I have found many article on stackoverflow but doesn't work.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
```

for reference

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:checked="true"
      android:text="hello123"
      app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
      android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: It's still not change the tick color.

Comment: it's better work with `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox `. try with this.

Comment: I try it. It's just change the checkBox color, not tick color.

Comment: try these solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542693/how-to-change-check-box-tick-color-in-android)

Comment: Thank for your help but that solution will make checkBox animation disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="hello123"
            app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

checked = true https://prnt.sc/CGSUxigv9pmF

checked = false https://prnt.sc/sAgExyOoSUvf

Comment: It's still not change the tick color.