# Android replace checkbox style with custom drawable selector

Tags: android, checkbox

I have tried to make a xml selector with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shuffleon" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shuffleoff" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

and when I try to set the `backgroundDrawable` to the `checkBox` the checkbox doesn't replace the `CheckBox` style too:

```
  shuffle.setBackground(android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.shuffle, null));
```

Following this question: [Change icons of checked and unchecked for Checkbox for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192173/change-icons-of-checked-and-unchecked-for-checkbox-for-android) I need to set the `button drawable` with my xml: `android:button="@drawable/checkbox"` but I can't do this because I'm creating the `CheckBox` programmatically.
Is there a way how to achieve this?

Comment: did you try with yourcheckbox.setButtonDrawable();

Comment: I didn't know there is such command, please post this as an answer to help others too.

Comment: Have you tried my code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use below line of code, i think it will work

```
yourcheckbox.setButtonDrawable(yourdrawable);
```

Comment: In my case it is the same as `android:button`.

Answer (score 25):

## Simple way

1. Create a new layout in drawable folder and  name it custom_checkbox (You can rename also)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/Checked_image_name"android:state_checked="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/Unchecked_image_name" android:state_checked="false"/>
   </selector>
   ```
2. Use this in your layout activity

   ```
   <CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/checkbox"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"/>
   ```

Comment: Probably `<item name="checkboxStyle">@style/YourTheme.CheckBox</item>` shouldn't be set for such customization.

Answer (score 5):

Use This

```
shuffle.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_checkbox_selector);
```

XML code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radiobutton_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radiobutton_unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use sdk 28 (androidx) and above try to use

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
```

instead of

```
Checkbox
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
android:button="@null"/>
```

Comment: It will resize an icon over the whole CheckBox (with text).

Answer (score 1):

drawable/checkbox_custome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_empty" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_check" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at https://m2.material.io/components/checkboxes/android#key-properties I found that we should use `button` and  `useMaterialThemeColors` (and maybe `app:buttonTint="@null"`):

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="text"
    app:useMaterialThemeColors="false" />
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_off" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

[image]

If you want to adjust styles do this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="checkboxStyle">@style/Widget.CheckBox</item>

<style name="Widget.CheckBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/selector_checkbox</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">your text appearance</item>
    <item name="useMaterialThemeColors">false</item>
</style>
```