# how to change the color of inside of checkbox?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

i want to change the checkbox color (white inside box) which currently look likes this [image: current], which should be like this. [image: desired description here]

Comment: make it custom and use selector

Comment: You can create a custom selector and then apply for your checkbox like this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183713/android-replace-checkbox-style-with-custom-drawable-selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183713/android-replace-checkbox-style-with-custom-drawable-selector)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of a CheckBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Add your required image in `drawable`

and add below property in **.xml** file

```
android:button="@drawable/img"
```

Where **img** is your required background

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add below line to your CheckBox's XML code

```
  android:button="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"
```