# Is there "FloatingToggleButton" or something like that in Android?

Tags: android

I want to use FloatingActionButton for "like" action, but there should be two states for this, liked and unliked. So ToggleButton is suitable for this, but is there anything that combines the feature of these two kinds of button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the checkbox with checked and unchecked images. so that you can able to manage it for like and like within same button action. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3193127/3632609) will help you to get the checkbox selector which use icons for different state.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this depend on your scenario,for eg if want to show like dislike only then use toggle button only and if want to perform some action then use floating action button with all the action..
Like for particular page change background black white,increase text size etc..All depends on scenario..And always try to choose best not to fail at any stage...For anything pls ask