# How to Set the Checkbox on the right side of the text

Tags: android, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show android checkbox at right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side)

In my android application, I have a checkbox and some text associate with it. By default the texts are in the right side and the checkbox in left side. But I want to put the checkbox on the right side. Help me please.

Comment: @CommonsWare has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3157228/310760

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I dont know whether it is possible or not by styling ,

But here is a solution for you

Use `""` as the value of the `CheckBox` ,then add a `TextView` to the left of the `CheckBox` with your desired text.

Comment: Is there any other way Without using two view?

Comment: Use `CheckedTextView`, it has the `CheckBox` to the right.

Comment: but what for radio butttons......

Comment: Any Tutorial or example of `CheckedTextView`?

Answer (score 39):

Very easy. Do it in an elegant way:

1. Create your own checkbox button. It includes a checked and unchecked state.
2. Edit your layout file, for checkbox node:

   1. Set `android:button="@null"`
   2. Set `android:drawableRight="@drawable/YOUR_CHECKBOX_BUTTON"`

Perfectly solve your problem.

If you want to put the text under your button, set `android:drawableTop`.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to easily modify a set of radio buttons into column sort headers using this.

Comment: This answer is much better.

Comment: What about preserving the default drawable?

Comment: @DanTumaykin use this `android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by:

1. taking a linear layout.
2. Put it's orientation to horizontal.
3. Then put a text view and then a check box.
4. Put the same text in the text view that you wanted to associate with the check box.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any other way Without using two view?

Comment: i faced the same prob.... then i used in the way i told...by default android places text on left of check box....

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But there are three component instead of one. and more complicated. :(