# how to change direction of checkbox android

Tags: android, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Set the Checkbox on the right side of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000213/how-to-set-the-checkbox-on-the-right-side-of-the-text)

I want to change the direction of the checkbox in android such that the text will be on the left and the checkbox is on the right. could you please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000213/how-to-set-the-checkbox-on-the-right-side-of-the-text , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side

Comment: @David kindly spend few minutes to search the question and only if the question is not asked, raise the question. Simply don't ask repeated questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to Use [`CheckedTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) for your requirement

Comment: CheckedTextViews are meant for ListViews.