# Align text left, checkbox right

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout for a ListView, with a checkbox to the right and some text to the left.  The checkbox should be aligned all the way to the right and the TextView  aligned all the way to left of the row, eg:

```
 ------------------------
 text            checkbox
 ------------------------
 text            checkbox
 ------------------------
 text            checkbox
 ------------------------
```

This is what I have so far:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingLeft="5dip"
      android:paddingRight="5dip"
      android:paddingTop="8dip"
     android:paddingBottom="8dip"
>

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" 
/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chekcbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" 
 /> 

 </RelativeLayout>
```

However, what actually renders is the TextBox is overlaying the checkbox, to the left of the row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show android checkbox at right side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since you are already using a RelativeLayout, make use of it's attributes:

Remove `android:gravity` from the children and replace them with `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` for the TextView and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for the CheckBox.

That positions the children relative to the parents borders. You may also want to add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to each child to center the two vertical within each list item.

*For further options and attributes see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).*

Comment: it's better to add android:layout_marginRight="36dp" to the TextView, if your text is too long, it will override the checkbox

Comment: Hi, what if I'm using a Linear Layout!! Can I still achieve, the checkbox compound button in right whilst the text in the left??

Answer (score 48):

And to get the checkbox's box to the right , in check box attributes

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

Comment: You sir, just saved my life. I've been struggling to find the default checkbox image and i was about to get the appcompat. +1 for '?' usage.

Comment: So this puts the `CheckBox` on the right side but the `AppCompat` widget tinting using the `colorAccent` doesn't work when you have the property 
`android:button="@null"` .  How can you get widget tinting with a `CheckBox` that is on the right side?

Comment: best answer i got

Answer (score 13):

for first time you must set `button` to `@null`

```
android:button="@null"
```

if you want to onl move android checkbox to right use :

```
android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

otherwise if you like to have custom image for checkbox use:

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/selector_check_box"
```

and for set gravity to right :

```
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
```

full action for use customize checkbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_on" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_off" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_off_pressed" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_off" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_on" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_on_disabled" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_off_disabled" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_off_disabled" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/_ics_btn_check_on_disabled" />
</selector>
```

images :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12):

My solution in this case is to use:

```
<CheckBox
...
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_check"
...
/>
```

where my_radio could be for example you custom selector!
Example of selector could be:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/check_checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/check_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Comment: So this puts the `CheckBox` on the right side but the `AppCompat` widget tinting using the `colorAccent` doesn't work when you have the property 
`android:button="@null"` .  How can you get widget tinting with a `CheckBox` that is on the right side?

Answer (score 6):

Use this as your LIST / RECYCLER ITEM.
The below 2 lines are the key.

**android:textDirection="ltr"
 android:layoutDirection="rtl"**

```
<CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            />
```

Comment: What happens to the view if Locale is changed to RTL?

Comment: That's a very valid point, as of now I didn't check that would be great if you check and update the answer if you have a finding.

Comment: I have used CheckedTextView for my purpose

Answer (score 5):

At the basis of Oibaf it's or MSaudi's solution

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

to add

```
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
```

to avoid the empty space at the checkbox left side in some device. The source link:

[How to show android checkbox at right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side)

answered by zeusboy.

Comment: So this puts the `CheckBox` on the right side but the `AppCompat` widget tinting using the `colorAccent` doesn't work when you have the property 
`android:button="@null"` .  How can you get widget tinting with a `CheckBox` that is on the right side?

Comment: to toobsco42: Sorry, i don't encounter the scene you mentioned. Maybe you could create a question with the detail of  your layout file and code, and somebody will give a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by adding layoutDirection to "rtl"

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="@string/declare_info_correct" />
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying to do this myself, I finally did it. You just need to put a TextView and a CheckBox in a horizontal layout, and put the gravity on the layout to the right.

Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:gravity="right"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/LabelText"
        />
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ChecKBox_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: I just noticed that you wanted text all the way to the left side of the screen. this will put the check box all the way to the right, and the text right next to it on the left side of the check box.

Like this:

```
------------------------
           text checkbox
------------------------
           text checkbox
------------------------
           text checkbox
------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `match_parent` for layout_width and `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` are enough:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/taxDevRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="ELIGIBLE FOR TAX" />
```

Comment: `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a relativelayout you might want to consider using the less annoying relativelayout attributes, alignParentLeft and alignParentRight, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="8dip"
    android:paddingBottom="8dip"
>

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignParentLeft="true"
/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chekcbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignParentRight="true"
/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just watch out for elements getting on top of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:gravity="start

```
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Has Diploma:"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_HasDiploma"
        android:gravity="start"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also remove 
android:orientation="vertical" since Relative layout does not support this attribute. It is attribute of Linear Layout.

You can try it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="check"
             />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chekcbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the switch:
Layout Parameters -> Width to "match_parent"

originally it's "wrap_content"