# draw thumb and tracker from switch button on left of text

Tags: android, widget

The default result when setting up a text on a switch button is the thumb/track on the right

```
+-------------+----------+
|             |          |
|  Lorem Ispu | on / off |
|             |          |
+-------------+----------+
```

What is to know if there is any way to make the thump/tacker being placed on the left side of the text without having to write a custom widget:

```
+-----------+-------------+
|           |             |
|  on / off | Lorem Ipsum |
|           |             |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found is to have Switch and TextView wrapped in LinearLayout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text:"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.
Idea was the same as mentioned here: [How to show android checkbox at right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side) I just reversed the order.

Answer (score -2):

To set default value of switch you have to define this code in xml

```
android:checked="true"
```

Comment: do you need some type of custom selector for your view?

Comment: no. the switch view is enough for me, but i really need the thumb and tracker on the left of text :/