# How to reposition CheckBox text relative to checkbox

Tags: android

The default text position of TextBox text is to the right of the text box.

```
[x] TEXT
```

How can re-position the text above the box?

```
TEXT
 [x]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side) seems like you just need to change drawableRight to drawableBottom.

You need to add the following line to your checkbox:

```
android:button="@null"
android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```