# Access scr for ImageView from CheckBox image by checking more than one CheckBox

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-checkbox

I am trying to change the image in an ImageView by accessing source of image in CheckBox. Here is part of my xml code

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage"
    android:id="@+id/img"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/image1"
     android:id="@+id/q4op1"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/images2"
     android:id="@+id/q4op2"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/images"
    android:id="@+id/q4op3"/>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/download"
    android:id="@+id/q4op4"/>
```

I want to check whether the CheckBox is checked or not. if checked then the image in **drawableRight** of that CheckBox should appear in the ImageView.

Can you guide me how can i write java code for this?

Comment: `cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);  if(cb.isChecked()) { .... }`

Comment: yes sir i know this about isChecked function but how to access the reference of the image from the particular checkbox

Comment: you mean you have multiple image? for each a checkbox determine which is which?

Comment: yes sir that images are right side of each CheckBox

Comment: but you have one imageview in your XML Layout. either have multiple with different ids such as image1, image2, ...  or add them dynamically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156781/how-to-show-android-checkbox-at-right-side

Comment: sir i have add image in right side of the checkBox whose name are image1,image2,images,download. is want one of these image in the imageView section if the ChechBox is checked, after clicking a button...

Comment: @arti please check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may solve your problem. Below code will get you all the drawables.

```
Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
```

Now, if you want to compare then you can use

```
Bitmap bmp1 = ((BitmapDrawable)drawables[1] ).getBitmap();
Bitmap bmp2 = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twt_hover)).getBitmap();

if(bmp1 == bmp2)
{
   //Code block
}
```

OR

in your case

```
// Left(0), top(1), right(2), bottom(3) drawables.
// This is the right drawable.
Drawable rightCompoundDrawable = drawables[2];
```

For checking if the checkbox is checked

```
cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.q4op1); 
if(cb.isChecked()) {
  // do your drawable task here
}
```