# Change ListView selected colour on Android

Tags: java, android, listview, colors, android-listview

So I have a listView on Android which I create in code like so:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menuitem, menuitems));

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ... });
```

Is there a way to change the selection colour in code from the default orange colour to another one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at: [Android ListView Selector Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color)

Comment: Yea, I saw that but is there a way to do this in Java as opposed to in XML?

Comment: You can use `StateListDrawable` class and then `listview.setSelector(stateListDrawable)`