# How to highlight ListView-Items

Tags: android, highlight, listviewitem

i got the following problem.

i have a ListView with custom rows consisting of an imageview and a textview.
the textview's xml code is

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textColorHighlight="#FEC403"
/>
```

then i have an itemclicklistener that works fine and i want to highlight the textview that has been clicked by doing the following.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adaptview, View clickedview, int position,
                long id) {
            //TODO: ACTIONS
            String pathtofile = (String) adaptview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            View rowview = (View) adaptview.getChildAt(position);
            rowview.setSelected(true);}
```

i wanted the highlight color to be "#FEC403" in the xml (that is a light orange) but the highlightcolor still is gray. so how to set the highlightcolor correctly?

thanks in advance

EDIT:

here is how i did it finally:

this is my ListView Item xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rowselector"
>

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/musicicon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/musicicon"
    android:paddingLeft="3px"
/>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:focusable="false"
/>
```

and the rowselector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/orange" />
</selector>
```

and at last my OnItemClick is very short now:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adaptview, View clickedview, int position,
                long id) {
            //TODO: ACTIONS
            clickedview.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ListView Selector Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color)

Comment: Unfortunately this technique cannot be used to highlight multiple items in the listview, because only one item can be selected at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a `Selector`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color) question and its answer might help....

Answer (score 10):

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3)
        {
            for(int a = 0; a < parent.getChildCount(); a++)
            {
                parent.getChildAt(a).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long itemid) {
            itemOnclickList(position, view);
        }
    });

    public void itemOnclickList(int position, View view) {      
    if (listview.isItemChecked(position)) {                           
       view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_checked));            
    } else {    
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_uncheck));           
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

In your Adapter:

```
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listdocument_item, null);      

        ListView lvDocument = (ListView) parent;
        if (lvDocument.isItemChecked(position)) {
            convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_checked));               
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_uncheck));               
        }

    return convertView;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look using selector:

Create a file within drawable called `selector_listview_item.xml`, which looks like (change the colors to your own):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/md_grey_200" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Now in your layout which describes the list row (e.g. layout_list_row.xml), On the root layout add the `android:background="@drawable/selector_listview_item"`, So the layout would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_listview_item" <!-- this is the important line -->
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- more stuff here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

(Note: you might want to add `android:focusable="false"` on you items within that listview row, to make the row clickable, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955270/listview-items-are-not-clickable-why))

Done.