# ListView text size

Tags: android

I am not having much success finding how to set the textSize for a ListView in the xml code - do I have to create a style?  any suggestions?
Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the textSize for a ListView, because a ListView is only the parent-View.

If you want to change the textSize, you have to change it in the child-Views ([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)).

A similiar question here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color).

Comment: here is a code sample that demonstrates how to code a custom listview row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412449/how-to-highlight-listview-items/4413985#4413985