# Deselect selected item in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

To make item selected in `GridView` I use `setSelection` instide I didn't found how can I make item *deselected*.

How can I acheive this ?

Comment: Have you tried `setSelection(-1)`?

Comment: Also apply for gridview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097793/cant-unselect-listview-item