# Disable Android ListView selector

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listview-selector

I am trying to disable the ListView selector on my ListView. I set the List Selector color to a transparent color. This seems to do the trick, but when I select certain text, they change colors. How can I make things work ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best solution, but for me it worked:

You can set the text color manually (in xml or at runtime)

Answer (score 33):

In your XML where you declare the ListView use:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/my_list" android:listSelector="#00000000" />
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer since it shows clearly WHAT needs to be set in order to modify the list selector.

Comment: yes agreed, this appears to be a bug in android i was using @null which does not work, this does.

Comment: Perhaps android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" would me more readable

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for ListView 's `setClickable(false)` and `setEnabled(false)` method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of selected items to match your background. This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color).

Answer (score 0):

Apply below code to your list view.

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```