# How to change textcolor in Listview on focus?

Tags: android

I am trying to change text color in listview on focus but it is taking the default one.  Please tell me how can we provide dynamic color to text and its background in listview?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a custom listselector Drawable. I'm sure this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color) is what you are looking for.

Comment: will u plz elaborate how can we do this?

Comment: Everything is present in that post. You create the custom_selector.xml file and than in the your layout you pass to the attribute android:listSelector your custom_selector.xml.