# How to highlight the row of the Custom List View when focus comes on that row.

Tags: android

We have created custom listview by using the Base adapter. List view contains Text View and Edit Text. My requirement is that when focus is coming on the row only that row has to highlights and when focus changes new focus row has to highlights and Old row becomes the normal. I have tried by using set background color but when I set Color to one row and goes to another row previous row has to change normal and new focus row becomes color but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just define a selector.xml file with:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

And apply it inside the `<ListView>` by using **`android:listSelector="@drawable/selector.xml"`**

### Useful Tip:

Whenever you want to change the color for a particular view on different state like pressed/focused/selected then just define a **selector.xml** file and then apply it using either **android:background (in button)** or **android:listSelector (in listview)**.

Enjoy!

Comment: I have tried the above solution it's working. But my requirement is little different. In above solution when user clicks the text view highlight but it's focus goes.... But I want when user clicks on one row then then focus remain till we pressed on other focus

Answer (score 0):

You need to write one Selector XML to Specify the Background color/drawable of Row when any event(pressed/focused) occurs like **[THIS EXAMPLE](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html)**

Other Same Kind of Question I think **[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color)**,**[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)**