# Changing color of selected listview item

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using the [FileExplorer library](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/) (open source) for Android in my project. The problem is that an item (file) selected in the list of the FileExplorer is shown in highly unreadable gray color. I'd like to customize this, but don't see any place where the color is assigned.

Activity source code does not contain any management of colors.

And here is the layout of list item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/fdrowimage"
    android:layout_height="35dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" android:paddingLeft="3dp"></ImageView>
<TextView android:text="@+id/fdrowtext" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fdrowtext" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fdrowimage"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fdrowimage" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fdrowimage"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:textSize="23dp"</TextView>
```

If I add `android:textColorHighlight` with custom color to the TextView, it does not take any effect. If I add `android:textColor`, it works, but changes text color for all items, which is not what I need.

Also I see a strange mention of color gray in strings.xml, but changing this value does not produce an effect as well.

Comment: you may want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color

Comment: @blacharnia: thank you, i know about selectors. What i'd like to grasp is how changes of color for selected items work in a listview in general without any selectors? Where do these colors come from? Is there a way to alter them 'inplace', so to speak? I prefer to use most efficient (minimal in efforts, without workarounds) methods among existing ones. There are no selectors in the project, and they could look a little bit artifical in the situation, where color change upon item selection does already work without selectors, and all I want to change is the value of the selected color itself.