# Android ListView Background color

Tags: android, listview, background

I want each even item in the `ListView` to be of different color. For this purpose I used the following code :

```
public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            if (c.getPosition() % 2 == 0) {
                row.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.dark_item_background));
            }

            holder.populateFrom(c, mDbHelper);
        }
```

But the item isn't highlighted after the touch event. Please advice how to overcome this.

**Update**

As Gophermofur advice I created a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_activated_holo" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/item_back_color"/>

</selector>
```

Now it works on Jelly Bean and does not on Gingerbread. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in a listview aren't actually defined as solid colours (black or white), they are defined using selectors where there are multiple colours for different states (normal = black, pressed = orange, focused = blue, etc).

When you start replacing the background colour of items in the listview with a solid colour, it overrides that selector so there are no longer different colours for different states.

Normally a listview selector is applied to the entire listivew, however, you may be able to apply it directly to an item's background or selector (I'm not sure and I can't test at the moment).

Take a look at these links to see how to create a selector XML file:

[Tutorial](http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/listview-selector-and-custom-background)

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color)

Comment: it's clear about selectors, not really about how can I apply directly to at item's background or selector.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the R.drawable.dark_item_background with R.drawable.[Selector_Name]? Selectors, once created and put in the drawable folder, should be given a resource id and you should be able to reference them like you would reference any drawable.

Comment: I have tried this approach. It works on Jelly Bean and does not on Gingerbread. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

> Now it works on Jelly Bean and does not on Gingerbread. Any thoughts?

I'm not sure what your drawable/list_activated_holo is, but by the name of it it sounds like its using the android Holo theme - which was only added in API level 14. 
http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html

You'll need to define the colours in your own values/colors.xml if you want to use them on devices running less than API level 14.