# ListSelector color change (while selecting list) and also put text-color (black) for Spinner does not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, spinner, android-spinner

Hello i want to change default orange color to red while selecting list item from spinner below is my code

To put Text in middle in spinner list and remove radio button in selection i have make custom adapter

```
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.range, R.layout.middle_text_spinner);
spBAFirst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now xml file for middle_text_spinner is below...

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:textColor="@color/tabDark"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" />
```

Now Image of spinner is  below

[image: SPINNER]

First of all i want to change color of this Middle text to **white** instead of **black**

but **when the list open all the text must be BLACK and white background but in some phone text will become white**

[image]

Now i want to change **default color orange** to **RED** while selecting the list

I have Googled but can not change color while selecting

i have tried with **listSelector** but it can not be done and used  also below is my code

this is in drawable folder btn_red_color.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/red" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/red" />
   <item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

and set this value to spinner **listSelector**

```
 <Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spBAFirst"
   style="@style/my_cust_text"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="35dp"
   android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
   android:listSelector="@drawable/btn_red_color" />
```

and my_cust_text style is

```
  <style name="my_cust_text">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:entries">@+array/range</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">-3dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">-3dip</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

but it is not working :( please can any body help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have find solution by this way you can be surely do it 90% of your work :) You can show **RED highlighted** color

[image]

make CustomAdapter called MySpinnerAdapter...

```
  MySpinnerAdapter adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(MySettings.this);
  spBAFirst.setAdapter(adapter);


 static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}

private class MySpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String[] array;

    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.range);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // A view to hold each row in the list
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.middle_text_spinner, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.text.setText(array[position]);
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_red_color);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

put this file in drawable folder btn_red_color.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/red" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

Spinner's xml file is like this

```
  <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spBAThird"
                    style="@style/my_cust_text"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@color/red"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Middle_text_spinner.xml file is below

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@color/tabDark" />
```

so enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this threads:
[Android ListView Selector Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color)
[ListView item background via custom selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)
http://www.geekmind.net/2009/10/android-custom-listview-selector.html