# How to disable click style in android GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a android.widget.GridView and I'm setting  setOnItemClickListener() on it. It works perfectly but adds a style to the UI when a cell is clicked. Any ideas how to remove this style?

Answer (score 2):

Ok thanks @Sam you got me on the right track. Could not get  `<item android:color="#00000000" />`to work, I think for grids you need to use drawables along the lines of [Android ListView Selector Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color). In the end my code that works is

Java code:

```
mygrid.setSelector( R.color.empty_selector );
```

res/color/empty_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

res/color/transparent.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/transparent" />
```

Not sure if there had been an easier way but this has worked so I'm happy.

Comment: I wasn't 100% that the color state was the answer that you wanted, so I hadn't spent the time testing my example (yet). I'm glad you got a working answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to the color selector or [color state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). You can probably create a dummy selector, that has no alternate values, then set it to the GridView with `setSelector()` in Java or `android:listSelector` in XML.

---

A dummy selector, it is transparent:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="#00000000" />
</selector>
```