# I can't change background of the list item when it is clicked

Tags: android

I want to change the background of a list item when it is clicked, but it isn't working.

This is my MusicAdapter inner class :

```
class MusicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        Fill fill=null;
        public MusicAdapter(){
            super(GetMusics.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,song_list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            row = convertView;
            if(row==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                fill=new Fill(row);
                row.setTag(fill);
            }else{
                fill=(Fill)row.getTag();
            }
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
            fill.setRow(song_list.get(position));
            return row;
        }
    }
```

I also tried this, but again it didn't work:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lv.getChildAt(arg2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
    }
};
```

Here is my list_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/Peru"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/Tan"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/Peru"/>
</selector>
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the background to be changed only while the item is being actively pressed on, or to be changed permanently after the user taps on it once? Your `list_selector.xml` does the former. If you want to do the latter, you'll have to call `setBackgroundResource()` with a normal drawable, and not a selector.

Answer (score 0):

The `onItemClick()` passes the View you need to change the background of already.  Just set the background there.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use something called `Selector` and set it as `ListSelector`, please refer to this question [Android ListView Selector Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color)