# How to highlight selected list item in android?

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments, android

In my android application i have list view and detail view for each list item. For tablets i have shown list view of items and selected item's detail view as follows.

[image]

So my problem is how can i highlight the selected item after user clicks on list item.

I am using a BaseAdapter to load list view.How can i do this any idea??

**EDIT:**

Yes as chintan khetiya mentioned i have used following xml file as the background of list item but it will not delighted the selected item. What have i missed?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/abs__background_holo_light" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/action_bar_blue" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/action_bar_blue" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your Query :**

> my problem is how can i highlight the selected item after user clicks on list item.

I think you are asking about selector. Mean if the list row in focus state then it should be look different form all other row. Same thing when you press or Touch the Row.

For that you have to make [Selector.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color) File in Drawable folder and just put that selector file in your list row

That file should have different tag like `Focus-Click-Press` and change the Drawable as per state.

**Update :**

Just Replace Your icon and save in Drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_paly_press" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <!-- selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_play" android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_paly_press" android:state_focused="true"/>

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/p_play"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: yes chintan khetiya i have edited the question can you show me the wrong part of that code.

Comment: it is working for me same code i have paste here. something problem else

Answer (score 2):

The code similar to the following code below can be used to highlight the selected item for sure if other ways do not do that you need:

```
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int selectedPos = -1;
    Drawable selectedBackground;

    public MainSelectAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        selectedBackground =
              context.getResources().getDrawable(R.color.selecteditembackground);
    }
    public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
        selectedPos = pos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (selectedPos == position) {
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(selectedBackground);
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

And the in the main activity

```
  Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    myItemsToShow);

  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.flows);
  list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
  list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
                adapter.setSelectedPosition(pos);
    }
  });
```

With this approach, you take own control on the selected item highlighting, you have a listener to capture selection events and you set yourself the required Drawable.

Comment: This approach works well with `ArrayAdapter` but what if someone is using `CursorAdapter`?

Answer (score 1):

You can define in your styles.xml

```
    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="...">
        <item name="activatableItemBackground">@drawable/activatable_item_background</item>
    </style>

   <style name="ListItemContainerBase">
        <item name="android:background">?activatableItemBackground</item>
    </style>
```

In res/drawable define activatable_item_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_activated" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

item_pressed, item_focused..... are images in res/drawable-xxx

Define for each items in your view a layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ListItemContainerBase">
```