# How to change the listview's item color and keep it longer in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working with **Customized list-view** which is in **Slidepanel layout**.

Here i'm trying to change the color of that listview's each ITEM when the particular item is being clicked.
It is working fine, but here what i need is, i want to keep that changed color to be 
displayed untill i click the another item from the listview.

How to do this?Suggestions please.

Thanks for your precious time!...

**Note :** From the below code, i've set the **list_row_selector.xml** as the background for that customized listview.

**list_row_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

<!-- Selected --> 
 <item 
android:state_focused="true" 
android:state_selected="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 

<!-- Pressed -->
<item 
android:state_selected="true" 
android:state_focused="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/selected" /> 

</selector>
```

**color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<drawable name="focused">#ff5500</drawable>
<drawable name="selected">#FF00FF</drawable>
</resources>
```

Comment: You could use Android Asset Studio's official tools to generate holo pressed and selected states.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583163/how-can-i-always-highlight-curent-item-in-the-listview?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583163/how-can-i-always-highlight-curent-item-in-the-listview?rq=1)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645275/how-to-highlight-selected-list-item-in-android?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645275/how-to-highlight-selected-list-item-in-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your adapter, create an instance variable `int selectedPosition = -1;`

Then inside the `getView()` method check if selectedPosition == position of that element, set the list_row_selector as the background else, set a normal background.

Also, update the value of `selectedPosition` whenever an item is clicked and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter to refresh the list.