# ListView doesnt show onclick color after set background

Tags: android, listview, colors, onclick

i have a listview which has an adapter, which worked properly, but then i added some code because i wanted the rows to be different colors, after that, the onclick color doesnt show up.

Here is the code i added:

```
if (position % 2 == 0)
            vi.findViewById(R.id.parentL).setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.row1));
        else
            vi.findViewById(R.id.parentL).setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.row2));
```

Comment: what you need is to create a selector for you items background, which can react on the state changes (onSelect, etc.)

Comment: could you give me some more details please? Thank you.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color described

Comment: @QAMAR, that link won't help since Edgar wants different selectors for alternating listview items.

Comment: @Nickolaus, this is a good first step. You also need to set the listview selector to be transparent in addition to setting the listview item selectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL:DR

- Use selectors for listview items
- You need to set your overall listview background to be to transparent.

### Instructions

First, you need to set your ListView to to be transparent

Inside your Adapter's `onCreate()` method, set:

```
 ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list)).setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Next, inside `Adapter`'s `getView()` include the following code

```
if (position%2 == 0) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
} else {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector2);
}
```

where selector.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/translucent_red" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/translucent_red" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/translucent_red" />
    <item
     android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
</selector>
```

and selector2.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/opaque_red" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/opaque_red" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/opaque_red" />
    <item
     android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
</selector>
```

don't forget to include a colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
   <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
   <color name="blue">#00f</color>
   <color name="green">#0f0</color>
</resources>
```

### Sample Project

here are the files for a [sample project I configured for you](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwoEtwD1VShWT1FmLWhYa3Y5UFk/edit?usp=sharing). You probably want to do a Project > Clean before anything else.

Some files can be ignored in this app, since I modified an existing sample that did something very different.

### Screenshot

here is what my example app looked like

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Btw, this line: "((ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list)).setSelector(R.drawable.transparent);" is inside onCreate method of the activity, instead of adapter's getview, like it says, am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry. That was a copying and pasting mistake. Fixed that.