# ListView - next item highlight doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, highlight

I have a fragment with listView - it highlights pressed item (using setSelected(true) method in onItemClickListener). 
i also have 'next' button, which should, among other things, switch to next item by selecting it (highlight). If it's last item, listView should highlight the first one.

here's first code (which works):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    activeView=view;
                    nextPos = i+1;
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    //...
                }
            });
```

and here's the second method, which doesn't work:

```
 public void getNext(){
        if(nextPos==listView.getCount()) nextPos=0;


        //This doesn't work:
        listView.getChildAt(nextPos).setSelected(true);

        nextPos++;

        //...

    }
```

Where lays the problem? I tried using setActivated(true) instead, but it also didn't help.

Comment: try something like View asd=listView.getChildAt(nextPos); and after this asd.setSelected(true);

Comment: it still doesn't work. Highlight is set on previously pressed item

Comment: if you try with nextPos-1 what happens?

Comment: you should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color

Comment: nextPos-1 gives the same result. I write it for android 4.0 and higher. If it could help - here's my selector:

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/minter_alpha" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@color/minter_alpha"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_activated="false"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />

Comment: EDIT: problem solved - i used setItemChecked(int, boolean) to highlight item.