# Android RecyclerView select first Item

Tags: android, selection, android-recyclerview, highlighting

I'm using a RecyclerView to implement a NavigationDrawer.

I got click events working, but I can't figure out how to have the first item selected on App start and following that keep the selected item higlighted even if the drawer is not shown.

All I've been able to find is multi-selection in RecyclerView.

Comment: Add your code of the recyclerview and adapters,,etcc.. to see how can we help you ,)

Comment: @Smashing already solved my problem, it works :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually just implemented this in an app I am working on. So this method worked:

First create a variable to track the current selected position at the top of your adapter:

```
private int selectedItem;
```

Then in your Adapter constructor initiate the selectedItem value you would like:

```
public NavDrawerMenuListAdapter(Context context, List<NavDrawerItem> data, NavDrawerMenuListViewHolder.NavDrawerMenuClickInterface listener) {
        this.context = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.navDrawerItems = data;
        this.listener = listener;
        selectedItem = 0;
    }
```

Here I use 0 as this is the first item in my menu.

Then in your `onBindViewHolder(NavDrawerMenuListViewHolder holder, int position)` just check whether your `selectedItem == position` and set the background of some view to a seleted background like so:

```
if (selectedItem == position) {
            holder.single_title_textview.setTextColor(0xff86872b);
            holder.nav_drawer_item_holder.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        }
```

Here I set the text color to green and give the Realativelayout parent a gray background on start. You can, of course, customize this in any way you like.

To implement a selection of an item and keep the state I use the following method:

```
public void selectTaskListItem(int pos) {

        int previousItem = selectedItem;
        selectedItem = pos;

        notifyItemChanged(previousItem);
        notifyItemChanged(pos);

    }
```

This method I usually call from the OnClick() method.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you very much :) sadly i cant upvote your answer yet, im still lacking the reputation

Comment: This is the wrong way! The view items should have a background item which shows their state.

Comment: Please feel free to provide links to where the "right" way is. All stackoverflow answers had different versions. This one worked for me.

Comment: @drindt you still have not supplied any link to the correct way?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color
@drindt probably means that you need to use a selector and use state_selected to change an item in the list's state

Comment: Ahh okay that works. Just wondering whether it will be harder to keep the selected state persistent if you use a selector?

Comment: could you tell me how to select first item from recyclerView, Github repo is 
   https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android/blob/master/Example/javaapp/src/main/java/com/stripe/example/javaapp/fragment/discovery/DiscoveryFragment.java