# RecyclerView onClick problems

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I have been working on `RecyclerView` and when a user clicks on an item I want the recyclerview panel to be changed. For simple testing purposes I am making the text of the recyclerview item red when clicked upon. The clicking properly but when I scroll the `RecyclerView`, other items randomly turn red. These random items are not clicked upon and are becoming red by themselves when I scroll. I think my problem should be in the `onClick` method.

```
public class interestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<interestAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
public ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList();
public static MyViewHolder.ViewHolderClick click;
//public static MyViewHolder.ViewHolderClick click;



public interestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> objects) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        data.add(objects.get(i));
    }
}

public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interestpanel, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;

}

public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public void setClickListener(MyViewHolder.ViewHolderClick clicker) {
    this.click = clicker;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String current = data.get(position);
    holder.category.setText(current);


}

static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener { //implements View.onClickListener {
    TextView category;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        category.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
            holder.category.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }
    public TextView getCate() {
        return category;
    }

    public static interface ViewHolderClick {
        public void clicked(View view, int position);
    }


}
```

}
`

Comment: You should keep reference to which item has been clicked!. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167929/android-recyclerview-select-first-item/30169536#30169536 That should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite straight forward as we know recycler view recycle the view one you have changed the color of one view in the list view the color of that view remain of that color in your case red.So at the time of bind view holder you need to change the  color back to normal ifs not clicked in other way you have to maintain the position of the clicked view and change the color accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView uses same row reference multiple times via myHolder object.  Problem is at :

```
MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);  //this holder has multiple reference in recyclerView
holder.category.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

As Piyush suggests correctly, maintain a field in your model for click (boolean). And render clicks with check on this boolean. update the boolean at your onclick

What I normally do is:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder convosViewHolder, final int i) {

        convosViewHolder.name.setText(contacts.get(i).getName());
        convosViewHolder.phone.setText(contacts.get(i).getNumber());

        convosViewHolder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //turn red here
        });
    }
```

You can try either. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **I have done this in `onBindViewHolder()` method of `RecyclerView.Adapter` class**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    final MyModel myModel = mMyModelArrayList.get(position);
    viewHolder.aTextView.setText(myModel.getA());


    View view = viewHolder.itemView;

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "View where A: " + myModel.getA() + " is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

> **Imp Part**

Dont forget to add `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` in your RecyclerViews Layout i.e. Parent Layout

Eg:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
```

By this you can enable clicking on your RecyclerViews particular View

> **Explanation**

In `onBindViewHolder()` method of your `RecyclerView.Adapter` class you can get ViewHolders Class view by `View view = viewHolder.itemView;`

So by using that view you can set `onClick` event for that particular Item Click of RecyclerView