# How to autoselect 1st item from RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` in my app that contain a list of Menu and when i press one of them if will change items in another `recyclerView` but when i open my activity noone of `recyclerView` where there are the menu's are selected.

So the question is how can i open the activity and find the 1st item of the `recyclerView` selected?

I was trying to simulate an click by Handler but it was making my app slower.

Here is the code from my Adapter :

```
public class RecyclerViewMenu extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewMenu.MenuViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MenuConstructor> menuConstructors;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private int selected_position = -1;



    public interface  OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menucard,parent,false);
        return new MenuViewHolder(v, onItemClickListener);

    }


    RecyclerViewMenu(ArrayList<MenuConstructor> menuList){
        menuConstructors = menuList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MenuViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MenuConstructor currentItem = menuConstructors.get(position);

        if (selected_position == position) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));

        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(currentItem.getSfondoColor()));
        }

        holder.textView.setText(currentItem.getDesk());
        holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(currentItem.getFontColor()));




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return menuConstructors.size();
    }

    public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textView;

        MenuViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonName);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(listener != null){
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                                listener.onItemClick(position);
                                selected_position = position;
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }


                }
            });



        }
    }

}
```

And here is a screenshot of my activity as you can see "CICCIO" is my first item of the `recyclerView` but it was selected manually.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `selected_position` should be public in a Utils class and then you set `selected_position = 0` in onCreate:

```
public class Utils {
    public static final int selected_position = -1;
}
```

then you use it in onCreate `Utils.selected_position = 0;`
and in onBindViewHolder `if (position == Utils.selected_position)`

Of course you have to remove this line: `private int selected_position = -1;`

Comment: How to set the variable to public in static Utils?

Comment: so i have to create a Class a part called Utils?

Comment: Yes, the name is not important.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this in your activity:

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.performClick()
```

Comment: That's what i was doing in my Handler for simulate the Click but obv i can't put it without the handler onCreate because it will crash.

Comment: Yeah... You may need a handler..  So are you looking for a better performing solution?

Comment: yeah that's what i was looking for.

Comment: This is a kinda funky... but have you looked at this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167929/android-recyclerview-select-first-item

Comment: Yeah actually i yet saw it but i can't get where initialize the position variable

Comment: it should be a parameter in your onBindViewHolder in your adapter class..

Comment: @Kannan_SJD, I wanted to select first position, and passing position as `0`, but it's not autoselecting, code is     public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull ReaderHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(readers.get(0));
    }
, for stripe-terminal-android device connection.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use performClick() function..

```
if(positon == 0)
 holder.itemView.performClick();
```